# :not(..) selector not working in an insertion point

Tags: css-selectors, polymer, shadow-dom

As mentionned in the title, I can't make a *:not* selector work with the `select` attribute of a insertion point.

As it is shown here http://jsbin.com/lusof/1/edit :

- the syntax works with a querySelector
- a similar node is accessible if nor selected with the *not* selector

Did I missed something obvious ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a bug. You can follow the progress of fixing it here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370670